# Not able to use copy method on Range(Cells(n,n)) on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Any ideas on why the following works fine:

```
Sheets("dados").Range("A2:A4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Resultado").Range("A2:A4")
```

While this doesn't?

```
Sheets("dados").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(4, 1)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Resultado").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(4, 1))
```

I've also made a test just trying to set the font to bold. If I use Range("A2:A4") I can change any sheet even without selecting it. But if I use Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(4, 1)) it only works if the sheet is selected.

The reason I want to use range with cells arguments is that it is easier to use iterators without having to convert to string.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to refer to the sheets the cells are in.

```
Range(Sheets("dados").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("dados").Cells(4, 1)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Resultado").Range(Sheets("Resultado").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Resultado").Cells(4, 1))
```

You can simplify it a little bit by putting a With statement for one of them.

```
With Sheets("dados")
     .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(4, 1)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Resultado").Range(Sheets("Resultado").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Resultado").Cells(4, 1))
End With
```

Comment: I've also tested without the Sheets before the Range, and it works fine: `Range(Sheets("dados").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("dados").Cells(4, 1)).Copy Destination:=Range(Sheets("Resultado").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Resultado").Cells(4, 1))`